# Is there specification for this google API?

Tags: api, google-maps

I want an API that given a specific substring of a region, say kem, it'll give things like kemayoran, or kentucky.

I found one here:
http://maps.google.com/maps/suggest?q=k&cp=2&hl=en&gl=&v=2&clid=1&json=a&ll=-6.230664,106.55365&spn=0.498289,0.276031&src=1&num=20&numps=10

The result is here:

```
[,,,[["Karawaci, Tangerang, Banten, Indonesia",[[[0,8,,"0x2e69f94aa2ffbb19:0x501576d15005300",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[10,19,,"0x2e69f8e853d2e38d:0x301576d14feb9c0",,,,,,,,,,,37],[21,27,,"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",,,,,,,,,,,545],[29,38,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kebayoran Baru, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,14,,"0x2e69f16435820073:0x400c5e82dd4bfe0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[16,23,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[25,47,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[49,58,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kebayoran Lama, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,14,,"0x2e69f10e08ea97f5:0x400c5e82dd4bf80",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[16,23,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[25,47,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[49,58,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Karawang Regency, West Java, Indonesia",[[[0,16,,"0x2e69775e79e70e01:0x301576d14feb9e0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,546],[18,27,,"0x2e68e6398252477f:0xbc18a454fc8e9d7e",,,,,,,,,,,545],[29,38,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,546,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kembangan, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,9,,"0x2e69f773223661c9:0x400c5e82dd4c150",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[11,18,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[20,42,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[44,53,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kelapa Gading, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,13,,"0x2e69f53368e40397:0x400c5e82dd4c1f0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[15,22,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[24,46,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[48,57,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kota Tangerang, Banten, Indonesia",[[[0,14,,"0x2e69f8e853d2e38d:0x301576d14feb9c0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,37],[16,22,,"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",,,,,,,,,,,545],[24,33,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kalideres, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,9,,"0x2e69f8081bfecd17:0x400c5e82dd4c130",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[11,18,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[20,42,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[44,53,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Karang Tengah, Tangerang, Banten, Indonesia",[[[0,13,,"0x2e69f9f95eebc263:0x501576d15005520",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[15,24,,"0x2e69f8e853d2e38d:0x301576d14feb9c0",,,,,,,,,,,37],[26,32,,"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",,,,,,,,,,,545],[34,43,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kebon Jeruk, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,11,,"0x2e69f6fc585f2119:0x400c5e82dd4c140",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[13,20,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[22,44,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[46,55,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kembangan Selatan, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,17,,"0x2e69f771676956eb:0x500c5e82dd53ad0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[19,26,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[28,50,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[52,61,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kosambi, Banten, Indonesia",[[[0,7,,"0x2e6a037bcda7d61b:0x401576d14fed6d0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,37],[9,15,,"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",,,,,,,,,,,545],[17,26,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kelapa Dua, Curug, Banten, Indonesia",[[[0,10,,"0x2e69fc0f4b37da0f:0x501576d15005230",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9938],[12,17,,"0x2e69fc3f47733283:0x401576d14fed760",,,,,,,,,,,37],[19,25,,"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",,,,,,,,,,,545],[27,36,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9938,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kemayoran, Jalan Garuda, Jakarta Pusat, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,9,,"0x2e69f5b89e46703d:0x76e6e2a8b70371cf",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,5139],[11,23,,"0x2e69f5bbe23cfc87:0x9dd643c13bf677f5",,,,,,,,,,,17],[25,38,,"0x2e69f44a266b52a5:0x300c5e82dd4b890",,,,,,,,,,,9937],[40,62,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[64,73,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,5139,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kunciran, Tangerang, Banten, Indonesia",[[[0,8,,"0x2e69fbd50e260ba7:0x501576d15005260",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[10,19,,"0x2e69f8e853d2e38d:0x301576d14feb9c0",,,,,,,,,,,37],[21,27,,"0x2e418ad6c40db999:0xbed39aab8b1ab3e9",,,,,,,,,,,545],[29,38,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Klender, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,7,,"0x2e698cac516deacd:0x500c5e82dd535c0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[9,16,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[18,40,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[42,51,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Karet Tengsin, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,13,,"0x2e69f41ae77b1459:0x500c5e82dd53790",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[15,22,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[24,46,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[48,57,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kemanggisan, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,11,,"0x2e69f6934ab075f1:0x500c5e82dd53c70",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[13,20,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[22,44,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[46,55,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kebon Melati, Jakarta, Jakarta Capital Region, Indonesia",[[[0,12,,"0x2e69f423ac6f0a67:0x500c5e82dd537b0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,9939],[14,21,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x5371bf0fdad786a2",,,,,,,,,,,37],[23,45,,"0x2e69f3e945e34b9d:0x100c5e82dd4b820",,,,,,,,,,,545],[47,56,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9939,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0],["Kedunghalang, West Java, Indonesia",[[[0,12,,"0x2e69c6e837f5593b:0x401576d14fed5a0",1,,0,1,1,0,1,,,,37],[14,23,,"0x2e68e6398252477f:0xbc18a454fc8e9d7e",,,,,,,,,,,545],[25,34,,"0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485",,,,,,,,,,,33]]],2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37,,,,0.0059705396927272232,,0]]]
```

That is almost perfect. The catch i I do not know the latitude and longitude. It seems that 0x2c4c07d7496404b7:0xe37b4de71badf485 somehow encode those 2 numbers. However, I do not know.

Anyone knows the spec for that API? Is that private API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is private API for only use maps.google.com. If your application or program access to the access point continuously, your access would deny from Google.

Google provides official APIs for REST, you should use these APIs.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

Comment: That API is very fast and very accurate. The other API doesn't work. How do you know it's private?

Comment: I checked the network communication of maps.google.com in past, then I found it. Also I asked to Google, then they answered. How did you find this access point?

Comment: To use official API, you need to register your application; then get an API key at https://code.google.com/.

Comment: I used live http header and see that it's the URL google has been calling.